# How to find all file sizes under Windows folder?

Tags: windows-10

My Windows folder size is nearly 500 GB and I can't find which folder or file size is huge. Is there any way to find this huge file?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try free [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) program for a nice, graphical overview of size of files on your drive. This will certainly help to see the biggest files on your disk or in a specific folder.

There is also quite a few [alternative programs to visualize disk space](https://www.howtogeek.com/113012/10-best-free-tools-to-analyze-hard-drive-space-on-your-windows-pc/), but I didn't try them.

Comment: There is also a portable version which doesn't need anything installed. It can be found at https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/windirstat_portable